# Why a method works perfectly but crashes if I put it inside a dispatch_async?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I have this camera app.

I take the image from the camera, process it with a filter and at some point inside `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` I take the final image and write it to a file using this:

```
    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
    [myself writeToVideoImage:resultadoFinal
             withSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
     CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
```

works wonderfully but If I put this inside a queue, like this:

```
    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);        
    dispatch_async(_writeToVideoQueue, ^{
      [myself writeToVideoImage:resultadoFinal 
               withSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
      CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    });
```

it crashes on the line

```
[_assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:presentationTime];
```

of

```
- (void)writeToVideoImage:(CIImage *)resultadoFinal
         withSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{

  CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
  CMTime presentationTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

  CGRect extent = [resultadoFinal extent];

  if (!_readyToWriteVideo) {
    _readyToWriteVideo = [self setupAssetWriterVideoInputWithSize:extent.size];
    return;
  }
  else if (_videoWritingStarted) {
    _videoWritingStarted = NO;
    // ***** CRASHES HERE ************
    [_assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:presentationTime]; 
  }


  CVPixelBufferRef renderedOutputPixelBuffer = NULL;

  OSStatus err = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL,
                                                    _pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool,
                                                    &renderedOutputPixelBuffer);
  if (err) return;

  [_ciContext render:resultadoFinal
     toCVPixelBuffer:renderedOutputPixelBuffer
              bounds:extent
          colorSpace:_sDeviceRgbColorSpace];

  [self writeToFile:renderedOutputPixelBuffer
      comSampleTime:presentationTime
               size:extent.size];
  CFRelease(renderedOutputPixelBuffer);
  CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
}
```

I don't have a clue of what is going on.

It appears to be something deallocating. I first suspected `sampleBuffer` was deallocating but I am retaining it inside and outside the function, just in case. I have also tried to create a copy of `resultadoFinal` inside the block, before calling the method, with no success.

Xcode shows the error

> [AVAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:] Cannot call method when status is 0'

There are questions on SO about that. I have tried all suggestions without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds as if you're doing something to the asset writer after you dispatch the write, but before it executes (vague, I know).  A brute force approach might be to observe `status` (KVO) and see if something changes it to the value that's being rejected.

Comment: I don't know much about AVAssetWriter, but the error "Cannot call method when status is 0" sounds like something isn't initialized properly - remember when you use dispatch_async you are running on a different thread, so maybe something needs to be initialized on that thread?  Just a thought

Comment: @JeffLoughlin - simply BRILLIANT! I was using 3 queues, one to display the video on the screen with ultra high priority, another with high priority to write frames to disk and a third with medium priority to do miscellaneous stuff. That approach is recent and by mistake the `AVAssetWriter` initialization was happening on another queue, not the one which was writing the video. Now it is working like silk. THANKS! Please make this comment an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @PhillipMills, you and Jeff were right but Jeff nailed it in the head... Thanks for your comment too. I have +1 you. THANKS

Comment: Brilliant because it shifted my point of view. I was looking what might be wrong with the video routines but your comment made me look at the dispatches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Cannot call method when status is 0" sounds like something isn't initialized properly - remember when you use dispatch_async you are running on a different thread, so you need to initialize your AVAssetWriter on that thread.

Comment: simply BRILLIANT! I was using 3 queues, one to display the video on the screen with ultra high priority, another with high priority to write frames to disk and a third with medium priority to do miscellaneous stuff. That approach is recent and by mistake the AVAssetWriter initialization was happening on another queue, not the one which was writing the video. Now it is working like silk. THANKS!

Comment: I don't know that "brilliant" is how I'd describe my answer...like I said above, I don't know much about AVAssetWriter, so it was just a guess - but I've been around this iOS stuff long enough to recognize some of the common problems and the kinds of errors that appear when you run into them (which don't always make it clear what the actual problem is...). Glad I could help.